# Perl - Redirect loop when redirect and setting cookie

Tags: perl, redirect, cookies, cgi

I am a Perl newbie, and i'm stuck with ths problem:

I have a _login.cgi script who manages the login and redirects to the index.cgi page when credentials are correct:

```
if (functions::check_credentials($input{"username"}, $input{"password"}) eq true ){

$session = new CGI::Session("driver:File", undef, {File::Spec->tmpdir});
$session->param("name", "Carcarlo Pravettoni");

$cookie = $page->cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id);
print $page->redirect( -URL => "index.cgi" -cookie=>$cookie);

} else {...}
```

but when I try it with correct credentials, i get an infinite redirect loop to _login.cgi (this script itself).

Instead, if I don't send the cookie with the redirect, all works:

```
if (functions::check_credentials($input{"username"}, $input{"password"}) eq true ){

$session = new CGI::Session("driver:File", undef, {File::Spec->tmpdir});
$session->param("name", "Carcarlo Pravettoni");

$cookie = $page->cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id);
print $page->redirect( -URL => "index.cgi");

} else {...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo here (missing comma after `"index.cgi"`):

```
print $page->redirect( -URL => "index.cgi" -cookie=>$cookie);
```

I would suggest that you enable [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) (and possibly [`diagnostics`](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html)), and refactor the code till there is no errors/warnings.

Comment: Thank you!
And... (still a newbie) if I enable strict and warnings, can I see them in the apache error log?

Comment: @qwertoyo Yes, errors/warnings should show up in the error log.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (functions::check_credentials($input{"username"}, $input{"password"}) eq true )
```

If you don't have `use strict` turned on, then this is probably accidentally doing what you want it to.

Perl doesn't have Boolean primitive types, so Perl is probably interpreting that `true` as the string `'true'`. And it's likely you're making the same error in the `check_credentials` function as well, so the two errors are cancelling each other out.

The more "Perlish" approach would be for `check_credentials` to return true or false values (perhaps `1` and `undef`) as appropriate and for the `if` statement not to check for specific values.

```
if (functions::check_credentials($input{"username"}, $input{"password"})) { ... }
```